# Recreate a form in CakePHP 1.3 from $this->data?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I've got a Cake application with a reports query interface, where the admin user can filter the data by various inputs in a form and the results are then displayed on the screen. I am looking for the simplest way to add a button which allows the user to download the results of this same query as CSV.

I'm sure I can create one for myself if I have to, but is there already a way to regenerate any given form based on $this->data? That way, I can just add .csv to the form action and use RequestHandler to choose the right output format.

Answer (score 0):

[here take a look at the following...
instead of finding the data from Db you can simply pass $this->data to it.
take a look at follo
[Exporting data to CSV the CakePHP way](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/jeroendenhaan/2010/04/23/exporting-data-to-csv-the-cakephp-way)

Comment: Thanks. I've read that article, but unless I missed something, I don't think it solves my problem. Exporting CSV is not the problem; I want to be able to take the report shown on the screen and offer it as a CSV download, which requires replicating the filter criteria that the user has chosen.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to replicate the function on your controller, one for generating the results on screen and another same function intended for csv, but on the function for csv it must have parameters which are similar to the values of $this->data. Use javascript to redirect on the function for csv.